# Elegant way to extract fields from a string with nested delimiters in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11

**Goal**:
Given a string `x` in the form

`<key1>=<value1>|<key2>=<value2>|...|,<key1>=<value1>|<key2>=<value2>|,...,`,

where `|` is the delimiter for separating key-value pairs, `,` is the delimiter for separating a set of key-value pairs, and `=` is the delimiter for separating the `key` and `value`, extract the set of key pairs and map them to an index starting at `0` in the same order that they appear in the string.

**Example**:
`x = "make=Honda|model=Civic|year=2011|,make=Acura|model=TL|year=20|,make=Lexus|model=ES|year=2021|,"`

**Result**:
`0` -> map containing `make=Honda`, `model=Civic`, `year=2011`
`1` -> map containing `make=Acura`, `model=TL`, `year=2007`
`2` -> map containing `make=Lexus`, `model=ES`, `year=2021`

**Constraints**:

1. Must compile with C++11.
2. Cannot create helper functions. I am restricted to only writing inside the `int main()` function.
3. Cannot import external libraries. Has to be done only using the `std` namespace.

**What I tried**:

```cpp
// vector of maps where each index is linked to a map of key pairs
std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> list; 

// this is the input string
std::string s = fields.str();

std::string outerDelimiter = ",";
std::string innerDelimiter = "|";

size_t outerPos = 0;
std::string outer;

// outer loop that will try to find and split on the ',' delimiter
while ((outerPos = s.find(outerDelimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
    outer = s.substr(0, outerPos);
    
    size_t innerPos = 0;
    std::string keyPair;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> pairs;
    
    // inner loop that will try to find and split on the '|' delimiter
    while((innerPos = outer.find(innerDelimiter)) != std::string::npos) {
        int splitIndex = outer.find('=');
        std::string key = outer.substr(0, splitIndex);
        std::string value = outer.substr(splitIndex + 1);
        
        pairs[key] = value;
        
        outer.erase(outerPos, innerPos + innerDelimiter.length());
    }
    
    list.push_back(pairs);
    
    s.erase(0, outerPos + outerDelimiter.length());
}
```

<strike>I am able to solve the sub-problem of extracting all of the key pairs from a single set, but when I tried to introduce a second loop to try to repeat this process for multiple sets of key pairs, I get a segmentation fault.</strike>

**Edit**:
I was able to solve my own problem:

```cpp
string s = "make=Honda|model=Civic|year=2011|,make=Acura|model=TL|year=2007|,make=Lexus|model=ES|year=2021|,";
    
vector<map<string, string>> v;

string d1 = ",";
string d2 = "|";
string d3 = "=";
    
size_t i = 0;
while( (i = s.find(d1)) != string::npos ) {
    string segment = s.substr(0, i);
        
    map<string, string> pairs;
        
    size_t j = i;
    while( (j = segment.find(d2)) != string::npos ) {
        string pair = segment.substr(0, j);
            
        int splitIndex = pair.find(d3);
        string key = pair.substr(0, splitIndex);
        string value = pair.substr(splitIndex + 1);
            
        pairs[key] = value;
            
        segment.erase(0, j + d2.length());
    }
        
    v.push_back(pairs);
        
    s.erase(0, i + d1.length());
}
```

**Follow-up Question**:
Would this problem be easier to solve if the form of the input string was this instead?:

`<key1>=<value2>|<key2>=<value2>|...,<key1>=<value1>|<key2>=<value2>|...`

**Example**:
`x = "make=Honda|model=Civic|year=2011,make=Acura|model=TL|year=20,make=Lexus|model=ES|year=2021"`

Comment: You should use a debugger to follow along in the code. That will make it easier to find what is going wrong.

Comment: "Cannot create helper functions. I am restricted to only writing inside the int main() function" that is one of the most irresponsible things to ask from someone that is learning. Writing clean and organized code is one of the most important skills a programmer must have and must be taught and practiced from the very beginning.

Comment: Hi @bolov, sorry for not clarifying that point. This restriction does not actually come from someone telling me that I can't do that. My company's software product has a feature that allows you to write mini C++ programs that interact with certain exposed internals of the application. However, these mini C++ programs are limited in the sense that you can only write code as if you're writing inside `int main()`. It's a hard restriction on the software itself.

Comment: @Hid I see.  I apologize for making assumptions.